# Wave Validation Tool - WCAG 2.1 - Why are my select elements failing

Tags: accessibility, wcag

I am really challenged by the wave (web accessibility evaluation tool) reporting that a client's website has 4 contrast errors. After scouring the code, it turns out the problem they are reporting is that the select elements have a problem with contrast, showing a foreground color of 0000ff and a background color of ffffff

Problem is that I corrected the css declarations to have all select elements with a color of black 000000 and background of white ffffff  I also declared !important and they show these values in the inspector window.

What in the world am I missing? Is it an issue with the wave tool?

Here is a link to the specific report [Wave Diagnostic Report](http://wave.webaim.org/report#/https://www.abcautocare.com/)

Comment: Go figure, when I browse to the link in Google Chrome it shows not errors, only in Firefox...

Comment: I am thinking this "popular" wave tool is crap...it shows one thing from one browser to another, another from extension to their online tool. I am thinking a tool such as powermapper is a much more thorough solution. Your thoughts?